# Organic Groups - types of nodes allowed to create

Tags: drupal, organic-groups

Wondered if someone can shed some light on OG groups in Drupal.

I know you can restrict what types of NODES that can be created within groups, but what if yuo have two types of groups. Can you restrict the creation of a certain type of node to only one group ?

Example:
I allow users to create groups called Sports
I allow uses to create groups called Movies

I have two types of nodes: Food & Shoes
Can I set that the Food node, can only be created inside the movie group
And set that the Shoes node can only be created inside the Sports group ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core behavior of OG is that every Content type defines it's own relationship to OG. They might be barred from a group relationship, a group node, or a group post. There is nothing in that base configuration to specify the relationship between a content type and each group type individually.

However, there are a few tricks you could put in place to try to facilitate something.

#### Cheap Trick

For example, if you hide the navigation to create a node of a given content type, you've cut off the obvious approach.

#### OG User Roles

Probably the most conventional trick I can think of would be to carve up the different content types on a permissions level. I'm not entirely positive this will work, so it will bear some experimentation.

1. Create a *Sports Writer* role, limit the ability to create and edit Basketball nodes to it.
2. Use [OG User Role](http://drupal.org/project/og_user_roles) to automatically promote members of the Sports group types into the Sports Writer role.

#### Cutting Edge Shenanigans

You can also use the [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces) module to toggle content type availability by [Feature](http://drupal.org/project/features). In fact, the implementation of spaces_menu_alter() might show you how you could programmatically build out the functionality you are looking for. Sounds like it would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Shoe/Food node, there is a dropdown/select list to choose the group it gets added to, right?

It should be possible to write a module that implemented `hook_form_alter` to intercept the node form for the food and shoes node and do a lookup based on the node type to filter the groups made available to it.

**edit** This module seems to exist, it may do what you require: http://drupal.org/project/og_content_type_admin